# XMLSerialization for a List

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have class like this below shown. which contains the shopping items where the number can vary from 0 to n.

```
namespace SerializationPOC
{

   public class ShoppingItems
   {
     public string CustomerName { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
   }

   public class Item
   {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to get the class serialized like to get the XML Schema like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ShoppingItems>
<CustomerName>John</CustomerName>
<Address>Walstreet,Newyork</Address>
<Item1>Milk</Item1>
<Price1>1$</Price1>
<Item2>IceCream</Item2>
<Price2>1$</Price2>
<Item3>Bread</Item3>
<Price3>1$</Price3>
<Item4>Egg</Item4>
<Price4>1$</Price4>


<Item..n>Egg</Item..n>
<Price..n>1$</Price..n>
</ShoppingItems>
```

I would like to know if this can be achieved by using the Serilization if not whats the best way to achieve this Schema?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do it with .net sezialization technics, I think that the only way is to do it by your self, but you know when you have a xml file like this, it's a bit difficult to querying ( even with other languages ), I suggest to use something like 
<Item id=1>
<Name>Milk</Name>
<Price>1$</Price1>
</Item>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard serializer that supports that layout. You will have to do it yourself. Personally, I would say "you're doing it wrong"; I *strongly* suggest (if it is possible) using a format like

```
<Item name="IceCream" Price="1$"/>
```

or

```
<Item><Name>IceCream</Name><Price>1$</Price></Item>
```

both of which would be trivial with `XmlSerializer`.

LINQ-to-XML is probably your best option, something like:

```
var items = new ShoppingItems
{
    Address = "Walstreet,Newyork",
    CustomerName = "John",
    Items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Name = "Milk", Price = "1$"},
        new Item { Name = "IceCream", Price = "1$"},
        new Item { Name = "Bread", Price = "1$"},
        new Item { Name = "Egg", Price = "1$"}
    }
};

var xml = new XElement("ShoppingItems",
    new XElement("CustomerName", items.CustomerName),
    new XElement("Address", items.Address),
    items.Items.Select((item,i)=>
        new[] {
            new XElement("Item" + (i + 1), item.Name),
            new XElement("Price" + (i + 1), item.Price)}))
    .ToString();
```

Comment: I dont have much say in the XML schema. So I will have go with the XElement or XmlWriter to achieve schema required. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please have a look on my article, [[^]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/347758/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization)

As an example you can look into the below code. The **Serialize** method is given on the article.

```
var test = new ShoppingItems()
                           {
                                CustomerName = "test",
                                 Address = "testAddress",
                                  Items = new List<Item>()
                                              {
                                                  new Item(){ Name = "item1", Price = "12"},
                                                  new Item(){Name = "item2",Price = "14"}
                                              },
                           };

            var xmlData = Serialize(test);
```

And it will return the string given below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <ShoppingItems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CustomerName>test</CustomerName>
    <Address>testAddress</Address>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Name>item1</Name>
            <Price>12</Price>
       </Item>
       <Item>
           <Name>item2</Name>
           <Price>14</Price>
       </Item>
   </Items>
</ShoppingItems>
```

Comment: a: that isn't the structure the OP requested, and b: that article is nothing more than a very basic glance of the most trivial usage of XmlSerializer; frankly the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) would be a MUCH better resource